# Jquery UI supported on Epub readers

Tags: epub, epub3

I am new to EPUB. I was trying to implement the modal dialog featue of the Jquery UI in an EPUB book. Can anybody provide me names of EPUB readers that fully support EPUB3 and JQuery version of the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of readers and their support here (JS support is listed in the "notes" column): http://www.mathjax.org/resources/epub-readers/.

Right now, iBooks is the only place that really has full JS support for device reading (Readium is great for web). Kobo is likely to catch up soon on their Android reader though! For now: test on iBooks!